# How do I create an offline React iOS app?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to build a React (NOT React-Native), offline (no REST calls) app that can be deployed to iOS? Just working on a learning project and don't want to deal with React-Native. Just want to use my current web skills and make an iOS app with just React.

Looking for a workflow/tools that would enable me to do so.

Comment: If you know react, react-native will not be that hard to pickup. All react-native does is use react (among other things) to efficiently map js to native code. So you could use 'just react', but you will have to rewrite react-native in the process to build to ios.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Apache Cordova`](https://cordova.apache.org/). Remember that achieving native-like performance will be problematic.